# Выставить div в линию?

Tags: html, css

[image: Проблема]
В чем проблема ?Когда в каком то диве много текста , рядом стоящие дивы съезжают.

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu div {
width: 120px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #863232;
white-space: pre-wrap;
text-align: center;
height: 50px;
}

.menu {
background-color: #323232;
height: auto;
left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
height: 50px;
}
.menu div a {
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
height: 100%;
color: #000;
}

    <div class="menu">
        <div title="TEST 1"><a href="">TEST 1</a></div>
        <div title='TEST TEST TEST 2'><a href="">TEST TEST TEST 2</a></div>
        <div title='TEST TEST TEST 2'><a href="">TEST TEST TEST 2</a></div>
        <div title="TEST 1"><a href="">TEST 1</a></div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Блоки `display: inline-block;` по-умолчанию имеют выравнивание - `baseline`, поэтому стоит задать выравнивание по серединке -   `vertical-align: middle;` :

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu div {
width: 120px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: #863232;
white-space: pre-wrap;
text-align: center;
height: 50px;
}

.menu {
background-color: #323232;
height: auto;
left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
height: 50px;
}
.menu div a {
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
color: #000;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div title="TEST 1"><a href="">TEST 1</a></div>
    <div title='TEST TEST TEST 2'><a href="">TEST TEST TEST 2</a></div>
    <div title='TEST TEST TEST 2'><a href="">TEST TEST TEST 2</a></div>
    <div title="TEST 1"><a href="">TEST 1</a></div>

</div>
```

Comment: При этом как можно еще отцентрировать текст когда стоит display:block;? ` .menu div a {
 display: block;
 font-size: 20px;
 height: 100%;
 color: #000;
 }`

Comment: добавила и выравнивание текста. это как один из вариантов

Comment: А можно ли как нибудь оставить height: 100%; либо растянуть на всю кнопку , и при этом оставить текст по центру ?

Comment: нет, проще тогда использовать flex